# I need get how much reactions has a message in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I was thinking of code like this to get the number of reactions a message has received after a set time:

```
  if (message.content == "test") {
  message.channel.send("Hi").then(msg => {
    msg.react('').then(r => {

  const react = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === ''
  const collector = msg.createReactionCollector(react)
  collector.on('collect', (r, u) => {
        setTimeout(() => u.send(r.length), 60000 * 5); 
  })
})
  })
}
});
```

But rightly .lenght is not the correct method to obtain the number of reactions, consequently the error is that the "r.length" message is empty and the bot cannot send it.

The goal is to send a message, as soon as you react to that message, a setTimeOut starts and at the end of the time it returns (in this case in private) the number of reactions that that message has received.

Answer (score 0):

`collected.size` is the right way of getting the number of collected reactions a message has.

You can read about reaction collectors **[here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#reaction-collectors)**

Here is a basic reaction collector that uses `collected.size`:

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;
};

const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });

collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
    console.log(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name} from ${user.tag}`);
});

collector.on('end', collected => {
    console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
});
```